# Javascript - How to make auto select another drop down

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, listfield

- Here have two list field menu. First
  `brand` second `item`
- I want if we
  select `brand` `IBM` that `item` will
  select `IBM` too
- In other hand, if we
  select `brand` `HP` that `item` will
  select `HP` too

How to do that in javascript.

```
<select name="brand">
  <option>Please Select</option>
  <option>IBM</option>
  <option>HP</option>
</select>

<select name="item">
  <option>Please Select</option>
  <option>IBM</option>
  <option>HP</option>  
</select>
```

Comment: I recommend that you add ID attributes to your select elements. Most of the answers below are using document.getElementById('brand') and document.getElementById('name').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <select name="brand" id="brand" onchange="document.getElementById('item').value = document.getElementById('brand').value">
   <option>Please Select</option>
   <option>IBM</option>
   <option>HP</option>
 </select>

 <select name="item" id="item">
   <option>Please Select</option>
   <option>IBM</option>
   <option>HP</option>  
 </select>
```

Answer (score 3):

I noticed your options line up with one another, so you could simply reflect the selectedIndex in in the second from the first:

```
document.getElementById("brand").onchange = function(){
  document.getElementById("item").selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an *onchange* attribute to your *brand* select element. When a brand is selected, then the *selectItem* function will be called, which in turn can select the item that matches the value in the *item* select element. Also, I recommend that you give IDs to your select elements so that you can use document.getElementById("brand").

```
<select id="brand" name="brand" onchange="selectItem(this.selectedIndex);">
  <option>Please Select</option>
  <option>IBM</option>
  <option>HP</option>
</select>
```

Here is the DOM reference for the select element:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_select.asp